# meta tag for iPad orientation issue

Tags: html, css, ios, ipad

Initially I used the meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, 
initial-scale=1.0/>
```

On using this tag, on initial load, the page looked good in landscape mode, but when I change the orientation to Portrait and back to landscape mode, the page zoomed out.

Then I tried the following meta tag on my page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
```

Though the page fits in landscape mode, I do not see a scrollbar to view more content on the Portrait mode.

Do I need to use media queries to make the page fit in both landscape and portrait mode or Is there a meta tag which will help achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good solution to this:

Meta Tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-  scale=1.0,maximum-scale=10.0,initial-scale=1.0" />
```

JavaScript with jQuery:

```
var mobile_timer = false;
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
$('#viewport').attr('content','width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-     scale=1.0,initial-scale=1.0');
$(window).bind('gesturestart',function () {
    clearTimeout(mobile_timer);
    $('#viewport').attr('content','width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=10.0');
}).bind('touchend',function () {
    clearTimeout(mobile_timer);
    mobile_timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('#viewport').attr('content','width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,initial-scale=1.0');
    },1000);
});
}
```

The script basically disallows zooming on the iPhone unless gestures are detected, just refeence it in your html and you should be good to go ;)
Source: http://www.ternstyle.us/blog/reset-iphone-zoom-on-orientation-change-to-landscape

I also set this media query for iPhones

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px)
{
    html
    {
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: That link is a great article! Thanks!